# Angular 5 import employees from csv

Tags: angular, csv

I want to import a CSV file and send it to a WEBAPI in blob. Here is my code.

**employees.html**

```
  <a href="#"><i class="icons fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>Import</a>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" accept=".csv" (change)="importCSV($event)"/>
```

**employees.component.ts**

```
importCSV(fileInput) {
  var myBlob = new Blob([fileInput], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
  console.log(myBlob)
    this.utilityService.importCSV(myBlob)
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
      },
      error => {
        console.log("ERR", error)
      });
}
```

**utilityService.ts**

```
  importCSV(file) {
      let headers = new Headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*','Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/utility/import',file,headers)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
      });
  }
```

Can you please tell me, how to import CSV in Angular 5?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JBNizet I want to convert my chosen CSV to blob and send it through webapi. I am trying locally.

Comment: That's not a question. If your question is "Why does this code cause an error?", the ask that question, and post the error. If your question is something else, then ask it. There need to be a question mark somewhere. Not just a story of what you're doing.